# Why did my question get closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

In reference to this question: [How to Write Floating-Point-based Image to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60460417/5241642), it's not clear to me at all how it got closed for being "Off Topic".

- I explained what my problem was
- I showed the code that I tried to use to solve my problem
- I explained how it didn't work, by referencing the debugging I had done

Why was the question closed?

Comment: The question is no longer closed.